# Integrating factor $e^{\int \frac{1}{x} dx}$ in differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

When integrating $\int \frac{1}{x} dx$, we typically write the integrated expression as $ln|x| + C$. The absolute value of the $x$-variable is introduced to account for the scenario where we have $ln(-x)$ and $x$ is a negative number.

In a calculus book I am currently working with, the following differential equation is used in an example:

$$xy'+y=3x^{2} +4x, x\neq 0$$

In this case the integrating factor becomes $e^{\int \frac{1}{x} dx}$. The textbook example then states that $e^{\int \frac{1}{x} dx}=e^{ln x} = x$.

**Question**: Why is it that we do not have to take the absolute value of the $x$-variable here? I could understand this if it was explicitly stated that $x>0$ in the given problem, but this is not stated. All we know is that $x\neq0$. So how does this account for the second scenario outlined above?

If anyone can explain this to me, then I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Logarithmic function $\ln x$ is not defined for $x < 0$. Hence, the integral of ${1 \over x}$ yields $\ln| x | + C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this, and perhaps this was clumsily written in my post. The absolute value expression is introduced in case we have $ln (-x)$, and $x$ is a negative number. In both of these cases we obtain $\frac{1}{x}$ when performing differentiation. The absolute value in the integrated expression accounts for this scenario. So why is this not done for the integrating factor in the differential equation?

Comment: Alternatively: taking $\log x$ here works even when $x$ is a complex variable (unlike $\log|x|$).  So beyond the elementary courses, we just use $\log x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

When you are solving the homogeneous $xy'+y=0$, you get

$$y=C\exp\left(-\int\frac{dx}{x}\right)=\frac{C}{|x|}$$

But then, since the solution is not defined at $0$, you have to consider either $x>0$ or $x<0$, so $|x|=\sigma x$ with a fixed $\sigma\in\{+1,-1\}$. This constant factor is already taken into account in $C$. So, with another $C$,

$$y=\frac{C}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks! This explains it. Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's because "doesn't matter" in the end, in the sense that, if $|x|$ is an integrating factor, then so is $x$.

So, even though what is (carelessly) written in your textbook is only valid for $x>0$, the integrating factor works everywhere.